# How can I make a prolog predicate that recursively counts down to 0. (swi-pl)

Tags: recursion, prolog, countdown

Given a number Num the predicate should count down from Num to 0, excluding Num. Trying to do this recursively, but only receiving one answer as output instead of the entire countdown.

Tried to subtract 1 from Num and then return this value recursively, with a basecase being in place for when Num is equal to 1 which would give the output CDN = 0. But somehow my code only returns the first number from the countdown. When tracing the output, it takes all the steps and doesn't fail, but ends up only returning CDN = 5 despite it having calculated all the other results for CDN.

This is my code:

```
countdown(0, 1). 
countdown(CDN, Num):-
    Num > 1,
    Num1 is Num1 - 1,
    countdown(CDN1, Num1), % Returns Num1 as Num
    CDN is CDN1 + 1.
```

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by "count down"? Do you want decreasing numbers as solutions on backtracking? Do you want a list of the numbers? Do you want to have them printed as a side-effect? Something entirely different?

Comment: Not clear if "recursively" is a requirement or you think it is necessary. If you want backtracking, you should avoid recursion if at all possible. If you want to collect a list or have a side effect, it is a bit more admissible.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is:

```
countdown(N, C) :-
    N > 0,
    C is N - 1.
countdown(N, C):-
    N > 0,
    M is N - 1,
    countdown(M, C).
```

Example:

```
?- countdown(3, C).
C = 2 ;
C = 1 ;
C = 0 ;
false.
```

A slightly better version is as follows:

```
countdown1(1, 0) :- !.  % avoid spurious choicepoint (that produces 'false' after last answer)
countdown1(N, C) :-
    N > 0,              % avoid recomputing predecessor of N on backtracking
    M is N - 1,         
    (   C = M
    ;   countdown1(M, C) ).
```

Example:

```
?- countdown1(3, C).
C = 2 ;
C = 1 ;
C = 0.
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much slago, if you don't mind I have some questions about the workings of the code. With the first solution you provided, how doesn't countdown return the same C value twice? Because the same N and C are provided and then N - 1 is executed... I don't understand why it wouldn't say C = 2, M = 2 and then C = 1, M = 1. 

And the second piece of code is definitely too complex for my brain haha, with the ; for or and the parantheses.

Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @slago too much code for absolutely no reason :-( and the `false` at the end of the first solution, and the cut in the second.... my heart is weeping :-D

Comment: @TA_intern Before criticizing my answer, show how you could solve this problem RECURSIVELY (as requested in the question), in a simpler way! BTW, you're not the only one who knows the predicate `between/3` and I didn't use it because, with it, the requested predicate wouldn't be recursive!

Comment: As to the simpler way, use succ/2. I will add my answer using succ/2 if OP clarifies what is REQUIRED and you haven't yet figured it out soon enough. If do figure it out you might even get your imaginary internet point back.

Comment: @TA_intern Actually, no... I don't know that feeling... and I stopped being an assistant professor at least 20 years ago... lol

Comment: @TA_intern If you are not able to see by yourself, note using succ is also not enough to have a recursive predicate! :-)

Comment: @TA_intern The requirement is on the tittle if the question... Did you read it?

Comment: Not on its own. However, it will count down, and it will fail at the end. So you don't need additional arithmetic and you don't need a guard (comparison). Try it out and ask if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @TA_intern Predicate succ is ISO? I'm still waiting for a simpler recursive answer without appealing to built-in and non-standard predicates!

Comment: Hehe don't start that silliness. Find a Prolog implementation that doesn't have succ/2; then, open a bug ticket on their bug tracker. If they don't have a bug tracker, don't bother mentioning it :-D

Comment: I wonder why there are people who take pleasure in being ridiculous... If I posted this question, I'm sure yours would be the best answer!

Comment: Please edit your answer somehow so that I can take away the minus vote.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show an alternative *method* (needs a tiny bit of tweaking to fit the specified requirements), using `compare`:

```
count_down(High, Low, N) :-
    % Ensures that High and Low are nonvar
    High >= Low,
    count_down_(High, Low, N).

count_down_(H, L, N) :-
    compare(C, H, L),
    count_down_comp_(C, H, L, N).

% Accept H as the counting-down value
count_down_comp_(_, H, _L, H).
count_down_comp_('>', H, L, N) :-
    % Decrement H towards L, and loop
    H0 is H - 1,
    count_down_(H0, L, N).
```

Example result in swi-prolog:

```
?- count_down(5, 3, N).
N = 5 ;
N = 4 ;
N = 3.
```